# Adding delimiters and removing commas

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, delimiter

I have a file from which I've output several columns of information, 4 to be exact.  At this moment they are separated by commas, but in order for my buddy to feed them into another script, he wants the format to be with '|' as delimiter and the commas removed.  The commas follow every set of data, so after my script outputs this:

```
[0], [1], [2], [3]
```

what I need is:

```
[0] | [1] | [2] | [3]
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt to do it yourself? If so, show the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s = "[0], [1], [2], [3]"

print s.replace(',', ' |')

# Output:
# [0] | [1] | [2] | [3]
```

will work for your test case.

Alternatively, you could get crazy with something like

```
s = "[0], [1], [2], [3]"

s = s.split(',')
s = map(str.strip, s)
s = " | ".join(s)

print s
# Output:
# [0] | [1] | [2] | [3]
```

Which may be more flexible depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> print ' | '.join('[0], [1], [2], [3]'.split(', '))
[0] | [1] | [2] | [3]
```

**UPDATE:**

Actually @jedwards's solution using `replace` is better:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("'[0], [1], [2], [3]'.replace(', ', ' | ')")
0.36054086685180664

>>> timeit.timeit("' | '.join('[0], [1], [2], [3]'.split(', '))")
0.48539113998413086
```